# Question about $t$-distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

> The random variable $T$ has a $t$-distribution with $20$ degrees of freedom. Find the value of $t$ such that
>   (a) $P(|T|>t)=0.98$
>   (b) $P(|T|>t)=0.05$

For part (b) am able to find $t=2.086$ but am having problems with the first one.
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: In a sea of question titles, this one really sticks out like a sore thumb.

Comment: its hard problem for me too

Comment: @J.W Perry: How about something more distinctive like "help me with my Math problem" :).

Comment: This is just a matter of looking at a t-table --and I'm not stuttering, I mean a t-table for the t-distribution with 20 degrees of freedom, and do a 2-sided cutoff.

Comment: @user99680 Indeed and indeed. :)

Comment: @user83845: here is a table for the t distribution. The degrees of freedom are listed in the column on the left. You also have a distinction between 1-tailed tests and 2-tailed tests: http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/gerstman/StatPrimer/t-table.pdf  . Can you take it from here?